# How do I load css files with a view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently trying to load a css file into a CodeIgniter view in the follow manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
```

A blank page is loaded. It seems that when I call the base_url function in the view the page doesn't load because the same thing happens when I call base_url() else where in the view but the page actually loads without css when I remove the calls to that function. Is there something that I need to require in order for the page to load?

Comment: Have you actually loaded the URL helper in your controller, via `$this->load->helper('url')` ?? Also, a blank page usually means a fatal error, but you have error displaying turned off. Google it.

Comment: what is the value of <?php echo base_url(); ?>. what is the absolute path to css file. alternatively you can try file bug toll by given the suggested path and monitor if it loading at real-time

Comment: loading the url helper fixed the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

This helper is loaded using the following code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

The following functions are available:

...

You need to first load the helper either in the method called, or in the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try import annotation.

```
<style> @import url('<echo base_url()?>/css/styles.css'); </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```